# WebMarkupMin.Mvc referring higher version of Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm using WebmarkupMin in some of my projects for some time now but when i started a new project today i had this problem with it's version and MVC version.

I'm using .NET MVC 3 and Visual Studio 2012, i already checked the version of WebMarkupMin on the website and it's ok, i downloaded it using NuGet, already tried to remove and add it again and nothing.

```
Assembly 'WebMarkupMin.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b'
uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' d:\Jobs em Andamento\Skill2015\packages\WebMarkupMin.Mvc.1.0.0\lib\net40\WebMarkupMin.Mvc.dll
```

My web.config also has a assembly binding that was there before i installed the WebMarkupMin:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I already tried to change the older version to 3.0.0.1 but i still get the same error.

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that when i added a third part lib ( HtmlAgilityPack ) it changed my version of the Razor dll in my packages.config, after i removed the reference from the project, changed the version on the packages.config and added a reference to the older version everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.1" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, it solved part of the problem, by the way your lib rocks, thanks for it.